# Class WP_Widget not found

Tags: php, wordpress

This is from an unsupported WordPress plugin that I'm trying to revive. I'm getting an error in the following code which states

> Fatal Error class WP_Widget not found on Line 7

It works with PHP 5.3.3 but not on 5.6 or any version of PHP 7. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<?php
/**
*
* Widget Class
*/
class Twitter_Like_Box_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    var $_options;
    function __construct( ) {

        global $tlb;

        $this->wpb_prefix = $tlb->get_domain();

        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'tlb_widget', 'description' => ' Display your Twitter followers along with a follow me button' ); // Widget Settings

        $control_ops = array( 'id_base' => 'tlb_widget' ); // Widget Control Settings

        parent::__construct( 'tlb_widget', 'Twitter Like Box', $widget_ops, $control_ops );

        $this->_options = $tlb->getOptions();
     }
    //Function to init the widget values and call the display widget function
    function widget($args,$instance)
    {
        $title          = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']); // the widget title
        $username       = $instance['username']; // the widget title
        $total_number   = $instance['total_number']; // the number of followers to show
        $show_followers = $instance['show_followers']; // show followers or users i follow
        $link_followers = $instance['link_followers']; // link followers to profile
        $width          = $instance['width']; // link followers to profile

        $widget = array ( 'username' => $username ,'total' => $total_number , 'show_followers' => $show_followers ,'link_followers'=> $link_followers, 'width' => $width, 'options' => $this->_options);

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( $title )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

        $this->display_widget($widget);

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
//function that display the widget form
    function form($instance)
    {
        global $tlb;

        $defaults = array( 'total_number' => 10, 'show_followers' => 'followers','link_followers'=> 'on','title' => 'My Followers', 'username' => 'chifliiiii');
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        <?php if( $tlb->error != '' && defined('DOING_AJAX')):?>
                <div class="error">
                    <p><?php echo sprintf(__('Check you <a href="%s">OAuth settings</a>, there is a problem with the connection.',$this->wpb_prefix),admin_url('options-general.php?page=twitter-like-box-reloaded'));?></p>
                </div>
        <?php endif;?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:',$this->wpb_prefix);?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>'" type="text" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
        </p>

         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('username'); ?>"><?php _e('Username (without @):',$this->wpb_prefix);?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('username'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('username'); ?>'" type="text" value="<?php echo $instance['username']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_thumbs'); ?>"><?php _e('Show Followers or people you follow?',$this->wpb_prefix);?></label>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" <?php checked( $instance['show_followers'], 'followers' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_followers'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_followers'); ?>"  value="followers"/> <?php _e('Followers',$this->wpb_prefix);?>
                </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" <?php checked( $instance['show_followers'], 'nofollowers' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_followers'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_followers'); ?>" value="nofollowers" /> <?php _e('People I follow',$this->wpb_prefix);?>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('total_number'); ?>"><?php _e('How many you want to show?',$this->wpb_prefix); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('total_number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('total_number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $instance['total_number']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link_followers'); ?>"><?php _e('Link followers to their profiles?',$this->wpb_prefix); ?></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['link_followers'], 'on' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link_followers'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('link_followers'); ?>" value="on" />

        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('width'); ?>"><?php _e('Widget width:',$this->wpb_prefix); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('width'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('width') ; ?>'" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($instance['width']) ? $instance['width'] : '100%'; ?>" />

        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=twitter-like-box-reloaded" title="" target="_blank"><?php _e('More settings',$this->wpb_prefix);?></a>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
        //function that save the widget
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
            $instance['title']           = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
            $instance['username']       = strip_tags( $new_instance['username'] )== '' ? 'chifliiiii' : strip_tags( $new_instance['username'] );
            $instance['total_number']   = strip_tags($new_instance['total_number']);
            $instance['show_followers'] = $new_instance['show_followers'];
            $instance['link_followers'] = $new_instance['link_followers'];
            $instance['width']          = $new_instance['width'];

            //Delete transient in case exist
            $key = 'tlb_widgets_' . $instance['username'];
            delete_transient($key);
            return $instance;
    }

    //Finally thevfunction that create the widget
    static function get_tlb_widget($widget)
    {
        global $tlb,$you;


        $wpb_prefix = $tlb->get_domain();
        $twitter =  self::fetch_twitter_followers($widget);

        ob_start();

        if( !empty($you['error']) && '32' == $you['code']) {

            echo $you['error'];
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">

            <?php echo $widget['options']['custom_css'];?>
        </style>

        <div id="tlb_container" style="width: <?php echo isset($widget['width']) ? $widget['width'] : 'auto';?>">
        <?php if(isset($twitter['error']) ) :?>
                <?php echo $twitter['error'];?>
        <?php else : ?>
                <div>
                    <div id="tlb_profile_img">
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $widget['username'];?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $twitter['profile_image_url'];?>" width="44" height="44" align="left" alt="<?php echo $widget['username'];?>">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tlb_name">
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $widget['username'];?>">
                            <?php echo $widget['username'];?><span> <?php _e('on Twitter',$wpb_prefix);?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tlb_follow">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $widget['username'];?>" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-width="65px" data-show-screen-name="false"><?php _e('Follow @',$wpb_prefix);?><?php echo $widget['username'];?></a>
                    </div>
                </div><br>
            <div style="padding:0; color:#637746;">
                <div id="tlb_follow_total">
                    <?php
                    if ( $widget['show_followers'] == 'followers')
                    {
                        echo $twitter['followers_count'].' '.__('people follow',$wpb_prefix).' <strong>'. $widget['username'].'</strong>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo __('You follow ',$wpb_prefix). $twitter['friends_count'].__(' users',$wpb_prefix);
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php for($i=0; $i < $widget['total']; $i++)    :?>

                    <span class="tlb_user_item">
                    <?php if($widget['link_followers'] == 'on' ): ?>
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $twitter['followers'][$i]['screen_name'];?>" title="<?php echo $twitter['followers'][$i]['screen_name'];?>" rel="nofollow">
                    <?php endif;?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $twitter['followers'][$i]['profile_image_url'];?>" width="48" height="48" alt="<?php echo $twitter['followers'][$i]['screen_name'];?>">
                            <span><?php echo substr($twitter['followers'][$i]['screen_name'], 0, 8);?></span>
                    <?php if($widget['link_followers'] == 'on' ): ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    </span>
                <?php endfor;?>
            <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <?php if ( $widget['options']['credits'] == 'true' ) echo '<div style="font-size:9px;text-align:right;">Widget By <a href="http://www.timersys.com/" title="Timersys">Timersys</a></div>';?>
        <?php endif;//twitter error ?>
        </div>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
        </script>
    <?php
        }
        $widget_code = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $widget_code;
    }
    /**
    * Display widget
    */
    static function display_widget($options){

        echo Twitter_Like_Box_Widget::get_tlb_widget($options);
    }
    static function fetch_twitter_followers($options)
    {
        global $tlb,$you;

        $cache_time = $tlb->_options['cache-time'];
        $id = isset($options['id']) ? $options['id'] : 'widgets';

        $key = 'tlb_'.$id.'_' . $options['username'];

        // Let's see if we have a cached version
        $followers = get_transient($key);

        if ($followers !== false)
            return $followers;
        else
        {
            $tlb->connect();

            $response = $tlb->connection->get("users/lookup", array('screen_name' => $options['username']));


            if (Twitter_Like_Box_Widget::is_twitter_error($response))
            {
                // In case Twitter is down we return the last successful count
                return get_option($key);

            }
            else
            {
                $json = $response;

                @$you['name']               = $json[0]->name;
                @$you['screen_name']        = $json[0]->screen_name;
                @$you['followers_count']    = $json[0]->followers_count;
                @$you['profile_image_url']  = $json[0]->profile_image_url;
                @$you['friends_count']      = $json[0]->friends_count;

                if ( $options['show_followers'] == 'followers' )
                {
                    $fans = $tlb->connection->get('followers/ids',array('screen_name' => $options['username']));
                }
                else
                {
                    $fans = $tlb->connection->get('friends/ids',array('screen_name' => $options['username']));
                }
                if (!Twitter_Like_Box_Widget::is_twitter_error($fans))
                {
                    if ($options['total'] > 90 )
                    {
                        $fans_ids = array_chunk($fans->ids, 90);
                        $fans = array();
                        foreach ( $fans_ids as $ids_a )
                        {
                            $fans_ids = (string)implode( ',', $ids_a );
                            @$result = $tlb->connection->get('users/lookup',array('user_id' => $fans_ids ));

                            @$fans  = array_merge($fans , $result );

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $fans_ids = (string)implode( ',', array_slice($fans->ids, 0, $options['total']) );
                        @$fans = $tlb->connection->get('users/lookup',array('user_id' =>$fans_ids));

                    }
                }

                if( !Twitter_Like_Box_Widget::is_twitter_error($fans) && isset($fans[0]->screen_name) )
                {
                    $followers = array();
                    for($i=0; $i < $options['total']; $i++)
                    {
                        $followers[$i]['screen_name']       = (string)$fans[$i]->screen_name;
                        $followers[$i]['profile_image_url'] = (string)$fans[$i]->profile_image_url;
                    }

                    $you['followers'] = $followers;
                    // Store the result in a transient, expires after 1 hour
                    // Also store it as the last successful using update_option
                    set_transient($key, $you, 60*60* $cache_time);
                    update_option($key, $you);
                }
                return $you;
            }
        }
    }
    static function is_twitter_error($response){
        global $you,$tlb;

        if(is_object($response) && isset($response->errors) )
        {
            $you['error'] = 'Error code: '. $response->errors[0]->code .'<br>Error message: '.$response->errors[0]->message;
            $you['code']  = $response->errors[0]->code;
            $tlb->log_error($you['error']);

            return true;
        }
        if(is_object($response) && isset($response->ids) && empty($response->ids))
        {
            $you['error'] = '<br>Error message: You got no users to show. check if you have followers';
            $tlb->log_error($you['error']);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

} //end of class
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress have ABSPATH variable defined in wp-config.php file, which contains the project's root path. Now we can include any file of wordpress codebase. eg.

```
require_once ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for the error, propably something with autoloading, but you can solve it if you include the file for the WP_Widget class in the first line.

```
require_once get_home_path()."wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php";
```